# Why isn't the puts method calling my .to_s method?

Tags: ruby, puts

I thought that defining a `to_s` method for a custom class meant that calling the `puts` method on that class would return an output as specified by `to_s`. In this program, however, I only get the result I crave if I write `puts bingo_board.to_s`. What is going on?

```
class BingoBoard < Array
  @@letters = %w[B I N G O]

  def initialize
    # populates an 5x5 array with numbers 1-100
    # to make this accessible across your methods within this class, I made
    # this an instance variable. @ = instance variable
    @bingo_board = Array.new(5) {Array.new(5)}
    @bingo_board.each_with_index do |column, i|
      rangemin = 15 * i + 1
      @bingo_board[i] = (rangemin..(rangemin+14)).to_a.sample(5)
    end
    @bingo_board[2][2] = "X" # the 'free space' in the middle
    @game_over = false
  end

  def game_over?
    @game_over
  end

  def generate_call
    ....
  end

  def compare_call(call)
    @bingo_board[@@letters.index(call[0])].include? call[1]
  end

  def react_to_call(call)
    ...
  end

  def check_board
    ...
  end

  def show_column(num)
    ...
  end

  def to_s
    result = ""
    0.upto(4) do |val|
      result += " " + @@letters[val] + " "
    end
    result += "\n\n"
    0.upto(4) do |row|
      0.upto(4) do |col|
        val = @bingo_board[col][row]
        result += " " if val.to_i < 10
        result += val.to_s + " "
      end
      result += "\n"
    end
    result
  end
end

my_board = BingoBoard.new
counter = 0
until my_board.game_over?
  puts my_board.to_s # renders the board in accordance with my to_s method
  call = my_board.generate_call
  counter += 1
  puts "\nThe call \# #{counter} is #{call[0]} #{call[1]}"
  my_board.react_to_call(call)
  gets.chomp
end
puts my_board  # renders bubkes (i.e., nothing)
puts "\n\n"
puts "Game over"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you'r extending from Array. That's why you're getting the wierd behavior. I don't see where you need the extending from so just remove that and things will work as you expect.

Here's a more detaled answer if you'd like to know why this is happening. Basically puts makes an exception for arrays so when an array is passed puts is called on each member. [Ruby Array#puts not using overridden implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977874/ruby-arrayputs-not-using-overridden-implementation)

Comment: Wow! That was a quick fix. But Array has its own to_s method. Why doesn't my custom to_s method override it, @jwater?

Comment: tl;dr of the link you left me: arrays are treated differently and no one really knows why. Is that a fair summary?
Also: is it then accurate to say the array to_s method cannot be overridden?

Comment: @pgblu - not exactly, it is overwritten and if you use some other method like say, print, it would call your to_s, but as long as your using the puts method then you are right.

Answer (score 2):

As @jörgwmittag said, this is a special case. The [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) method treats arrays - which means anything that responds to `to_ary` - differently. It calls `to_ary` first and then iterates over each element of the resulting array, and only calls `to_s` on them. It never calls `to_s` on the array itself.

If you delegate to a member array instead of subclassing from `Array`, you have finer-grained control over what gets "inherited" (delegated). Then you can exclude `to_ary` from the delegation, which will prevent `puts` from seeing your object as an Array and triggering this behavior.

Other general solutions:

1. Use string interpolation or explicit `to_s` calls so that what `puts` receives is already a string:

   ```
   puts "#{bingo_board}"
   puts bingo_board.to_s
   ```
2. Use `print` or `printf` instead of `puts`:

   ```
   print bingo_board,"\n"
   printf "%s\n",bingo_board
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If the object is an `Array` or can be converted to one (i.e. it implements `to_ary`), then `puts` will not call `to_s` on the object, but rather *iterate* over the object and print each object *within* by calling `to_s` on it.

See:

```
puts [1, 2]
# 1
# 2

[1, 2].to_s
# => '[1, 2]'
```

[This *is* actually documented](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0.preview1/IO.html#method-i-puts), although somewhat implicitly:

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it runs `Array#inspect` method instead of your custom `to_s`. Adding `alias_method :inspect, :to_s` just after ending of the `to_s` definition will help you.

But it'll work only with `p`, because `puts` runs `each(&:inspect)`.

Comment: OK. Now instead of pure bubkes I get []